# How to download and install Xuggler for Java?

Tags: java, video, streaming, xuggler

I would like to use Xuggler in my Java-Project. As far as i know, the support for this library stopped in 2011. The links on their download-page are all outdated and i couldn't find another source for the files. Now where can i get those files?

Im working on Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If *google* couldn't find it for you, no one can.

Comment: You can find the source code here (as mentioned on their website): https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler However, in that README they suggest to use https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video which seems to be maintained.

Comment: Think about your idea again: the project is dead for 6 years, and just getting access to the files of that product overburdens you... But you seriously consider to add this thing to your delivery? Sorry but how many more alarm bells need start ringing before you will listen? An to make sure you get the message: this is a terrible idea and instead of wasting your time on a dead project you better search for an alternative...

Comment: I need a simple library to encode a video. Xuggler offers a simple way to do that. Even though this library is pretty old, it's more than enough to do this job. Everything else would be overkill.

Comment: Until you run into a bug that is. Or you find that the Interfaces are horribly outdated by todays means so you start creating adapters all over the place to shield you from that. The crucial point is: anything that is part of your product adds risk to it. It is hard enough to deal with 3rd party components when the owners react poorly to your defects or feature requests. But you will not even have somebody to talk to!

Comment: Well, you are right in terms of the bugs and of course the support. May you suggest another library?

Answer (score 0):

**For everyone who his searching for this library too**

As dunni mentioned, the sources can be found here: github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler

The binarys here: http://www.compadre.org/osp/items/detail.cfm?ID=11606